# Segue Fires but screen doesn't transition

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

Using storyboards, I have a view controller which segues to another.

I have two segues, one from a button and one from the view controller.

I want to fire the view controller segue programmatically based on certain conditions, so in the viewDidLoad method of the first screen I call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SkipName" sender:self];
```

Using the debugger I can see that prepareForSegue gets called, but the view doesn't move on.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try it in viewDidAppear instead and see what happens.

Comment: What type of segue is SkipName?  Push or Modal? Or something custom?

Comment: Putting it in viewDidAppear did the trick, thanks @danielbeard ! :)

Comment: make sure to answer your own question and mark it as the answer if you figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it in viewDidAppear did the trick, thanks @danielbeard !

Also, to use a push segue the views need to belong to a navigation controller.  You dont' get any errors, it just doesn't work.