# Inconsistent transitions/segue fires but doesn't transition

Tags: ios, json, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

**DISCLAIMER**: This question does not answer my question: [Segue Fires but screen doesn't transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222798/segue-fires-but-screen-doesnt-transition)

I have a segue to a view controller that loads data from a JSON-file in the viewDidLoad-method. According to my timers, the function that extracts data from the file, only uses 0.2 seconds to complete, and my viewDidLoad-function completes after 0.21 seconds.

Although it seems like everything is "ready to transition" almost instantaneously, it doesn't do so until a whole 8 seconds!

Also, when I use a unwind-segue back to the original view controller, and then perform the same segue to the "JSON-loading" VC again, the segue either:

- uses a lot longer to transition.
- isn't able to transition.
- only transitions after I've pressed the screen once more.

Now according to my logic, I have a couple of possible scenarios:

1) The data loading really takes 8 seconds, but this really isn't very logical since my timers are put inside the function which loads the data.

2) The segue "gets confused" because of the small time-delay the viewDidLoad-function uses to complete, and then "is confused" for another 8 seconds until it transitions.

I've tried changing between show, modal and custom segues, but that doesn't make any difference.

If you need any more information about this, please ask. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm executing the segues from cells in a table view.

Comment: are you loading the data asynchronously?

Comment: @longbow no, I'm not. I just found out why it takes so long for the transition to happen: the populating of the graph takes 8 seconds. that still doesn't explain why the segue won't let the new view appear.